# MySQL query selecting max value

Tags: mysql

I have this two tables:

```
product
id | name
1  |  A
2  |  B

history
id_product | year | month | percent
1          | 2014 |   2   |  0
1          | 2014 |   3   |  20
1          | 2014 |   4   |  60
```

How can I get the highest percent if the month is the the current month or a month before, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM history 
WHERE id_product IN
     (SELECT id FROM product 
      WHERE id = 1) 
  AND ((year = 2014 AND month = 3) OR 
       (year = 2014 AND month = 2)) 
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
```

This would output: 20 but it actually shows 0, it always gives me the month's before value...Any suggestions are welcomed...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(hs.`percent`) as `percent`, hs.id_product, p.name FROM
(SELECT * 
FROM history 
WHERE ((year = 2014 AND month = 3) OR 
       (year = 2014 AND month = 2)) 
) as hs
LEFT JOIN `product` as p on p.id=hs.id_product
GROUP BY hs.id_product
```

Try this.